# How come only one line is telling me operator= is not viable? but others are fine?

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading, smart-pointers, initializer-list

I've been debugging this for almost 6 hours by now and I'm about to give up.
And yes, it's just a school project.  But I've already turned in my copy and now I just want to know why it isn't working.

In my smartPointer class I want to overload operator=.  It seems fine to me and should be good to go.  But no, one line of code in my initializer list constructor is causing compiler error.  I've marked it with "Problem here!!".  I don't see it being any different from same lines in other constructors.  If I comment it out, it will compile.  But obviously it will cause runtime error due to memory not allocated.  Is there anything I overlooked? Please give me some hint.  Oh, I know my code has potential delete problems such that same address get deleted more than once, but I want to keep debugging it on my own.  I just want to know why only that specific line is causing problem since that line exists in other constructors but are all fine.  Much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <initializer_list>


using namespace std;

//--------------------------------------------------------
//smart pointer class;

template <typename T>
class smartPointer{
private:
    T* pointee;  //raw pointer;

public:
    smartPointer(T* raw = 0):pointee(raw){}

    smartPointer(smartPointer<T>& rhs){
        pointee = rhs.pointee;
        rhs.pointee = 0;
    }   


    //destructor;
    ~smartPointer(){
        if(pointee !=0) delete [] pointee;
    }

    smartPointer<T>& operator=(smartPointer<T>& rhs){
        if(this == &rhs) return *this;
        delete pointee;

        pointee = rhs.pointee;
        rhs.pointee = 0;
        return *this;
    }


    T* operator->() const{
        return pointee;
    }

    T& operator*() const{
        return *pointee;
    }

    T& operator[](int i) const{
        return pointee[i];
    }


};

//smart pointer class;
//--------------------------------------------------------

template <typename T>
class SA{

private:
    int low, high;
    smartPointer<T> p;

public:
    //default constructor
    //allows for writing things like SA a;

    SA(){low=0; high=-1;p=NULL;}

    //2 parameter constructor lets us write
    //SA x(10,20);

    SA(int l, int h){
        if((h-l+1) <= 0){
            cout<<"constructor error in bounds definition"<<endl;       
            exit(1);
        }
        low=l;
        high=h;
        p=smartPointer<T>(new T[h-l+1]);
    }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//new code added below!!!!!!!!!

    //initializer list constructor;

    SA(initializer_list<T> l){
        int size = l.size();
        low=0; high=size-1;
        p=smartPointer<T>(new T[size]);    //Problem here!!!
        initializer_list<int>::iterator itr;
        itr=l.begin();
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
            p[i]= *itr;
            itr++;
        }
    }


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//new code above!!!!!!!!!

    //single parameter constructor lets us
    //create a SA almost like a "standard" one by writing
    //SA x(10); and getting an array x index from 0 to 9

    SA(int i){low=0; high=i-1;
    p=smartPointer<T>(new T[i]);
    }

    //copy constructor for pass by value and
    //initialization

    SA(const SA& s){
        int size=s.high-s.low+1;
        p=smartPointer<T>(new T[size]);
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            p[i]=s.p[i];
        }
        low=s.low;
        high=s.high;
    }

    //destructor

//  ~SA(){}

    int getHigh(){
        return high;
    }

    int getLow(){
        return low;
    }

    //overloaded[] lets us write
    //SA x(10,20); x[15]=100;

    T& operator[](int i){
        if(i<low || i>high){
            cout<<"index "<<i<<" out of range"<<endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        return p[i-low];
    }

    //overloaded assignment lets us assign
    //one SA to another

    SA& operator=(const SA& s){
        if(this==&s) return *this;
        delete[] p;
        int size=s.high-s.low+1;
        p=smartPointer<T>(new T[size]);
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
            p[i]=s.p[i];
        low=s.low;
        high=s.high;
        return *this;
    }

    //overloads << so we can directly print SAs

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const SA<T>& s){
        int size=s.high-s.low+1;
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
            os<<s.p[i]<<" ";
        return os;
    }

};



int main(){
    SA<int> z{10,20,30};
    cout<<"printing result for SA z {10,20,30};"<<endl;

    cout<<z<<endl;
    cout<<"SA z(1,3){10,20,30}; would not work because" <<endl;
    cout<<"both (1,3) {10,20,30} are parameters where the latter"<<endl;
    cout<<"one is a initializer_list. In addition, {} are used for"<<endl;
    cout<<" initialization not assignment. But this would work:"<<endl;
    cout<<"SA<int> x({5,6,7});"<<endl;

    SA<int> x({5,6,7});
    cout<<x<<endl;

//  SA<int> v(1,3){1,2,3};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I double checked but I'm not sure how to minimize this.  Both classes and the main functions are all used.  Every constructors are also used.  I got rid of some none used functions.  Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem with your code is the definition of the `operator =`. My advice for you is to read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators): Here there are the reasons why you should declare your assignment operator as `const` or change the definition using the `move assignment` for example. Anyway I found another way to easily implement smart pointers: [Implementing a simple smart pointer in C++](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15351/Implementing-a-simple-smart-pointer-in-c). As you can see there, it's used a specific class to count the reference to objects allocated.

(why don't you use `nullptr` instead of assign 0 to raw pointers?)

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I see::

1. `p`is an object of type `smartPointer<T>` . It is created on stack. Dont delete!!. Your are deleting it in the overloaded function for assignment
2. Your default constructor for SA is incorrect.
   Initialize `p` with `smartPointer<T>(nullptr)`. I would recommend using initialization list for constructors.

Apart from that your smart pointer is not smart enough:
Refer https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15351/Implementing-a-simple-smart-pointer-in-c

Comment: Thanks, you are right, p shouldn't be delete.  for 2, I already have a initializer_list constructor, isn't it enough?

Comment: Well, you don't need a default constructor until you use it. The point is you have set `p=NULL` . Since it is an object (and not a pointer), that statement is incorrect.

Comment: Were you able to fix your problem mate?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  These are also problems but they are not the ones causing my problem.